# How to add links to module control panel in Expression Engine 3.2.1

Tags: control-panel, module, ee3

I've created a basic module with its own control panel page. The page works, but I can't seem to hit upon how to make that page more visible in the backend.

How can I add a link on the main control panel sidebar?

Failing that, how can I link to my control panel page from the AddOn Manager listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to link settings from the AddOn manager - I simply needed to add [`'settings_exist' => TRUE`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/addon_setup_php_file.html#settings-exist) to my `addon.setup.php` array.